# Thymeleaf Binding list of objects

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Here's my Object that I've retrieved from the DB:

```
@RequestMapping("/category/edit/{id}")
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public ModelAndView displayCategoryList(@PathVariable("id")Integer id){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("category-form");
    List<CatFeatGroup> catFeatGroupList = catFeatGroupService.findGroupsForCategory(id);
    mav.addObject("catFeatGroupList",catFeatGroupList);
    return  mav;
}
```

Here's my form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div th:each="catFeatGroup,status : ${catFeatGroupList}" class="form-group">
        <label>Position</label><input th:field="catFeatGroupList[${status.index}].position"  th:value="${catFeatGroup.position}" />
        <label>Name</label> <input name="catGroupList[${status.index}].name" th:value="${catFeatGroup.name}" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I need to use `th:field` to bind that object however this error shows up:

> Could not parse as expression: "catFeatGroupList[${status.index}].position"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the "__" notation like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div th:each="catFeatGroup,status : ${catFeatGroupList}" class="form-group">
        <label>Position</label><input th:field="*{catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].position}"  th:value="${catFeatGroup.position}" />
        <label>Name</label> <input data-th-name="*{catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].name}" th:value="${catFeatGroup.name}" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very match.