# Spring Boot : How to bind list of objects on POST in thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a list of records on `GET` request which is shown on UI with a checkbox.

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("records", createRecords());
    return "list";
}
```

This is my `Record` `POJO`:

```java
class Record {
    private boolean selected;   
    private Integer id; 
    private String name;    
    private String phone;
    //....
```

I am showing in UI as below:

```html
<th:block th:each = "record : ${records}">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{selected}" th:checked="${record.selected}" /></td>
    <td th:field="*{id}" th:text="${record.id}" />
    <td th:field="${name}" th:text="${record.name}" />
    <td th:field="${phone}" th:text="${record.phone}" />
</tr>
</th:block>
```

I am having hard time to get the `List` of selected records on `POST` from `UI`. I just gets one object back from `POST`.

I want something like this in `POST` mapping:

```java
@PostMapping("/list")
public String select(@ModelAttribute ArrayList<Record> records) {
    //... at least ids of selected records
    //... or all the records back with selected
```

Please help.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500731/how-to-bind-an-object-list-with-thymeleaf.

Comment: @ben3000 i have the limitation of using the same object, instead of using wrapper object which has list of main objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of potential causes of your problem. The three items listed below should help you get the form mapped correctly:

1. You should build the form correctly, including using the `*` notation to reduce repetition, for example:

   ```
   <th:block th:each = "record : ${records}">
     <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{selected}"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" th:field="*{phone}"/></td>
     </tr>
   </th:block>
   ```

   As shown in the [Spring + Thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form)
2. You may need to use the double-underscore notation when looping over `${records}` to get each `Record` filled correctly in your form. As per [the Thymeleaf + Spring tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields):

   > ..`__${...}__` syntax is a preprocessing expression, which is an inner expression that is evaluated before actually evaluating the whole expression.

   See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33734995/2495717).
3. Double-check that you're handling the resulting list correctly in your Spring `@Controller` by accepting a `List<Record>` annotated with `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestParam`. (**It looks like you're doing this already.**)

   See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42341032/2495717).